# How to use XML as a data field in a JSON request in OpenAPI/Swagger?

Tags: java, spring, swagger-2.0, openapi, swagger-codegen

I need to create a REST endpoint which will consume a JSON request but this JSON object has a data field which is an XML file.

As shown in the example below, `Customer` is the request object which can hold address in JSON format (`AddressJson`) or XML format (`AddressXML`).

Can anyone suggest how I can use address in XML format (`AddressXML`)? In the end, I want an OpenAPI (Swagger) representation*.

```
"Customer": {
  "description": "A problem object",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "name of the customer",
      "example": "null"
    },
    "AddressJson": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/AddressJson/"
    },
    "AddressXML": {
      "type": "XML",
      "description": "address of the customer, specifically in XML format"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the actual JSON request with an `AddressXML` value?

Comment: Hi @Helen,
   the mentioned example is Swagger representation of the input Json. AddressXML can be simple xml fiel wiht fields like city, pincode etc.